# Before Insert Trigger error when executing insert

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

On a Before Insert trigger I want to calculate the value 
of a column based on two colums in the inserted record
and values of columns in other tables linked to the table being updated

Testing this I just created the code to access one of the
filelds in another table up the chain. But when executing I
had an error

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `infrastructure`.`Wall_Drop_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Wall_Drop` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Declare wall_temp decimal(6,2) default null;
Declare room_temp decimal (8,2) default null;

select r.dist_wire_closet into room_temp from rooms as r 
    where r.Residence_residence_id = new.Wall_rooms_Residence_residence_id
    and r.Residence_residence_id = new.Wall_rooms_Residence_residence_id;


END
```

Error message when inserting record
[image]

Comment: The error seems to be clear, more than one row is matching the `WHERE` criteria, but you can only use `SELECT INTO variable` with a single result.

Comment: Both of the tests in your `AND` are the same. Why do the same thing twice?

Comment: When there's more than one room with the same `Residence_residence_id`, which room should it use?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, 2nd line was the same as the first. I need

```
select r.dist_wire_closet into room_temp from rooms as r 
    where r.Residence_residence_id = new.Wall_rooms_Residence_residence_id
    and r.room_abr = new.Wall_rooms_room_abr;
```